# python3 jsonファイルデータの取得方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, json

jsonのデータの取り出しについて教えてください。

jsonファイルで

```json
{
  "totalItems": "1212",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "AAAAA",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "あああああ",
        "authors": "かか かかか",
        "publisher": "さささ",
        "publisherDATE": "2000",
        "description": "xxxx",
        "pageCount": "201",
        "previewLink": "http//"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "BBBBBBB",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "いいいいいい",
        "authors": "ききき きき",
        "publisher": "ししし",
        "publisherDATE": "2001",
        "pageCount": "250",
        "previewLink": "http//"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "XXXXXXXX",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "うううううううう",
        "authors": "くくく くくく",
        "publisher": "すすす",
        "publisherDATE": "2002",
        "description": "yyyyyyy",
        "pageCount": "280",
        "previewLink": "http//"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "YYYYYYY",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "ええええええええ",
        "authors": "けけけ けけ",
        "publisher": "せせせ",
        "publisherDATE": "2003",
        "description": "zzzzz",
        "previewLink": "http//"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ZZZZZZZZZ",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "おおおおおお",
        "authors": "こここ ここここ",
        "publisher": "そそそ",
        "publisherDATE": "2004",
        "previewLink": "http//"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

このjsonファイルの中で
description
pageCount
キーと値を削除してデータを取り出したいです。
それと、descriptionとpageCountキーの値がない場合のエラーを出さないようにしたいです。

自分が試したのは

```
json_file = open('JSONファイルの名前.json', 'r')
json_object = json.load(json_file)

print(json_object["items"][0]["volumeInfo"])
```

volumeInfoの階層までは取り出せたのですが、
次のtittle から previewLink までのデータを取得したいのですが、
ここからがどうしてもわかりません。
その階層までいけば、for文で回せばいいのかなって
思ってるのですが、、

書き方が読みづらいと思いますが、

どなたか、ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえずこんな感じでどうでしょう。
Pythonコードと実行結果を貼り付けておきます。
実行環境はpython3.7.0です。

```
# coding: UTF-8

import json

json_file = open('a.json', 'r')
json_object = json.load(json_file)

for item in json_object['items']:
  item_info = item['volumeInfo']

  print('======== 書籍ID: {} の情報 ========'.format(item['id']))
  print('タイトル: {}'.format(item_info['title']))
  print('著者: {}'.format(item_info['authors']))
  print('出版: {}'.format(item_info['publisher']))
  print('出版日: {}'.format(item_info['publisherDATE']))
  try:
    print('説明: {}'.format(item_info['description']))
    print('ページ数: {}'.format(item_info['pageCount']))
  except KeyError:
    pass
  print('リンク: {}'.format(item_info['previewLink']))
  print()
```

実行結果

```
======== 書籍ID: AAAAA の情報 ========
タイトル: あああああ
著者: かか かかか
出版: さささ
出版日: 2000
説明: xxxx
ページ数: 201
リンク: http//

======== 書籍ID: BBBBBBB の情報 ========
タイトル: いいいいいい
著者: ききき きき
出版: ししし
出版日: 2001
リンク: http//

======== 書籍ID: XXXXXXXX の情報 ========
タイトル: うううううううう
著者: くくく くくく
出版: すすす
出版日: 2002
説明: yyyyyyy
ページ数: 280
リンク: http//

======== 書籍ID: YYYYYYY の情報 ========
タイトル: ええええええええ
著者: けけけ けけ
出版: せせせ
出版日: 2003
説明: zzzzz
リンク: http//

======== 書籍ID: ZZZZZZZZZ の情報 ========
タイトル: おおおおおお
著者: こここ ここここ
出版: そそそ
出版日: 2004
リンク: http//
```

descriptionとpageCountのキーと値を削除してデータを取り出したい、というのはどういうことでしょうか？
json_objectからそれらのキーと値を削除したいということでしょうか？
それらの値が必要ない、というだけであれば、わざわざ削除しなくても、descriptionやpageCountの値を呼び出さなければ良いだけの話かと思います。
上の例であれば、try~exceptに囲まれた部分をコメントアウトしてしまう事がそれに当たるでしょう。

---

**追記**
もっとコードを汎化して短くしてみました。

```
# coding: UTF-8

import json

json_file = open('a.json', 'r')
json_object = json.load(json_file)
attributes = ['title', 'authors', 'publisher', 'publisherDATE', 'description', 'pageCount', 'previewLink']

for item in json_object['items']:
  print('======== 書籍ID: {} の情報 ========'.format(item['id']))

  for att in attributes:
    try:
      print('{}: {}'.format(att, item['volumeInfo'][att]))
    except KeyError:
      pass

  print()
```

実行結果

```
    ======== 書籍ID: AAAAA の情報 ========
    title: あああああ
    authors: かか かかか
    publisher: さささ
    publisherDATE: 2000
    description: xxxx
    pageCount: 201
    previewLink: http//

    ======== 書籍ID: BBBBBBB の情報 ========
    title: いいいいいい
    authors: ききき きき
    publisher: ししし
    publisherDATE: 2001
    pageCount: 250
    previewLink: http//

    ======== 書籍ID: XXXXXXXX の情報 ========
    title: うううううううう
    authors: くくく くくく
    publisher: すすす
    publisherDATE: 2002
    description: yyyyyyy
    pageCount: 280
    previewLink: http//

    ======== 書籍ID: YYYYYYY の情報 ========
    title: ええええええええ
    authors: けけけ けけ
    publisher: せせせ
    publisherDATE: 2003
    description: zzzzz
    previewLink: http//

    ======== 書籍ID: ZZZZZZZZZ の情報 ========
    title: おおおおおお
    authors: こここ ここここ
    publisher: そそそ
    publisherDATE: 2004
    previewLink: http//
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。コメントについてですが、volumeInfoの中の値にアクセスする方法がわからなかったので質問させていただきました。

Comment: コードを汎化して短くして作っていただいたコードの部分で質問なのですが、attributesを作ってその中にリストでtitleやauthorsを作ってますが、　　　　　　例えば items > volumeInfo > title で title が第3層目だとすると、　　　　　　　　それ以上の層（第4層以上）がある場合はどのようなアクセスの方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: もともとの質問は、第２層目から第３層目にアクセスしたいという質問だと言い換えることができます。それを踏まえて私のコードを見ればなんとなく想像はつくのではないでしょうか？第４層のattributeを集めて、それを元にまたfor文を回せばいいと思います。

Comment: そもそもjson_objectがどのようなデータ構造になっているかは理解していらっしゃいますか？全て、辞書型の入れ子構造になっています。「キー」がattribute、「値」が下位の要素を辞書型にしたものとなっています。ですので、第２層から第３層であろうと、第３層から第４層であろうと、データの取り出し方は一緒です。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。確かに理解不足でした。ありがとうございました！